# I duplicated products magento and my urls are product-1.html product-2.html

Tags: magento, url, url-rewriting

I have made my magento store (community)
I have used duplicate product on a lot of products and I didn't get that the URL key field had to be changed for every product i thought i would solve it self.

Now i have about 100 products and unfortunately they are now named example:

/HaircolorBlack.html , /haircolorblack-1.html, /haircolorblack-2.html and so on.

I wonder if there are any way to easy make magento re create the url after what the products meta title is?

This would be so helpful.

I saw this two year old post about approx the same thing but I didn't wanted to use that script since I don't know if it might break anything in my magento since its been so much updates. Here is link: [Clearing URL keys in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13844155/clearing-url-keys-in-magento)

Also I need total moron instructions on where to put the script to. Sorry ;)

Thanks a lot.

S

Comment: I tried with the script in the linked post but was unable to reach admin page. all went blank but went back to normal when i deleted the script again.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a one off script using magento itself.. add this script somewhere in your magento root folder (beside index.php):

```
<?php

  require_once "app/Mage.php";

  Mage::app('admin'); // must be admin to do changes

  function convertToUrlKey($string) {
    return $string; // I WILL LEAVE YOU TO SOLVE THIS PART
  }

  foreach(Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection() as $product):

     $metaTitle = $product->getMetaTitle();
     $urlKey = convertToUrlKey($metaTitle);

     try {
         $product->setUrlKey($urlKey);
         $product->save();
         echo "Assigned url key {$urlKey} to {$product->getName()}.\n";
     } catch(Exception $ex) {
        echo "ERROR: {$ex->getMessage()}";
     }

  endforeach;
```

Obviously this is not a complete solution as you will have to re-create the `convertToUrlKey` function for the correct behavior of converting 'Black Hair Color' to 'black-hair-color' and also ensure that there will be no duplicate url keys generated..

You can run the script by browsing to it or running through SSH:

```
$ cd magentoProject
$ php -f changeUrlkeys.php
```

Good luck!